# Redis Object - Get All Objects from DB - Profile View Counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, redis-objects

I am currently developing a membership website that include a view counter. Past experience says, having view counters in SQL is costly. I in fact kept away from view counters but today its not an option.

#### The project uses

- Rails 4.0.2
- Redis Objects gem
- For demonstration I am hoping to use Heroku with `Redis To Go` plugin
- Currently the counter is based on PG ( Active Record )
- Redis Objects have been used with AR to count ( but how to save to AR profiles table ? )

#### Need / Thinking of achieving

- Counts in Redis and periodically stores to PG table possibly using a Rake + schedule task
- Efficiency

#### Problem

- I can't figure out how to do a query the Redis DB to find all Profile objects in it.

If I could get this list of objects I can write a rake task to iterate through each item and save/update the modal value to the database.

After some search `KEYS profile:*` seems to be the only way to get all the profile values saved to the database. Then from it I have to manually fetch objects and update the values.

#### Question

1. Is using `keys` to find the keys and then the objects sensible ( in terms of efficiency ) to use in a scheduled task possibly once a day.
2. Is there a way to fetch all `Profile` objects directly from Redis db like we can do `Profile.all` in `ActiveRecord` ?
3. Any suggestions to implement a counter is highly appreciated ( even if not Redis based )

-

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  # To handle the profile counter
  include Redis::Objects
  counter :tviews

  # Associations

  belongs_to  :user

  # Other attributes
end
```

profiles_controller.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  def public 
    @profile.tviews.increment
    # @profile.save # Save of AR based counting
  end

end
```

In the SLIM

```
    p.text-center#profile-counter
      | Views - 
      = @profile.tviews.value + @profile.views
```

Answer (score 1):

1) No it's not. See [redis docs](http://redis.io/commands/keys) it says `Time complexity: O(N) with N being the number of keys in the database, under the assumption that the key names in the database and the given pattern have limited length.`

Not only redis would have to iterate over all the keys, it would have to store them in memory. Also due to single-threaded nature of redis it would be unresponsive for the time of executing keys command.

2) Not a ruby user here, but I would assume that not.

3) You have several options

- Store ids for your keys in a redis `set` and clean it with your periodic task (and redis transactions if needed). This way you'll always know exactly which keys are in redis.
- Use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command from redis 2.8 It returns only limited amount of key and iterates over keys using an internal cursor.

(redis.io seems to be down right now, so links might not be working)